# Can't understand a logic of Object And Array in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I write this line on `routes/web.php` file

```
dd( app()['config']["auth.guards.web"] );
```

It outputs this:

```
array:2 [▼
  "driver" => "session"
  "provider" => "users"
]
```

That's cool, but my question is since `app()['config']` returns an object so how this `["auth.guards.web"]`works? Even there is no index with that name!

Outside of Laravel I tried to write a class named Test so that it returns the same output but I got an error! Which is,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Test as array
```

Can anyone explain it with core php?

Comment: The object returned by `app()['config']` probably implements [`ArrayAccess`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.arrayaccess.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel contains a very useful helper function called `Arr::get()` which retrieves a value from a deeply nested array using "dot" notation. Laravel framework uses this helper function everywhere it needs to get the values inside a deep array; e.g configs and translation and so on.

Example;

```
config('database.driver');
__('validation.error');
trans('validation.error');
```

On the other hand, `app()['config']` returns `Illuminate\Config\Repository` instance which implements `ArrayAccess`. As long as `get` method of `Illuminate\Config\Repository` class uses `Arr::get` method, you can use "dot" notated array access along with `app()['config']`.

For more details, see these links; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-get
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php#L53

Comment: I got it,  ArrayAccess is a php's predefined interface and it provides accessing objects as an array. Thank you.